# How to declare an extension static function in Kotlin on Java Classes?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-extension, static-functions

I want declaring an extension func in kotlin but on Java classes Library, I know that do in Kotlin when you resolve `companion` in extension function.
Like:

```
class Food {
   companion object {
       fun foo() = Unit
   }
}

fun Food.Companion.clear(){/*Clear all of objects*/}
```

Now, are there any way for inject a `static` function on Java classes library?

Comment: As far as I understand it's not possible as long as a class have no companion object. Btw there is no "injection" of functions. The compiler transforms your `fun A.ext(): B` into a `static B ext(A receiver)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do it. That issue is already in tracked, please check [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/static-extension-methods-for-java-classes/2190) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Create a class somewhere in project named `Extensions.kt`. It should be looks like this:

```
package com.examplle.something

fun Food.clear(){
    /*Clear all of objects*/
}

fun User.xyz(){
    /*Do task XYZ*/
}
```

No need to make a class for this. It should be out of the class.

So finally we'll have a file `Extensions.kt` which contains only the extensions method directly without any `class` structure.

Comment: I want to inject a static fun in Java Classes library like `Navigation Component` that developed by Java

Comment: This will work fine with any class. Just replace the Food or User to specific class name that you want to insert a new method in.

Comment: You call it on objects. OP wants to call it on class. Imagine `fun Int.increment() = this + 1` being called like `1.increment()` not `Int.increment()`.